# Knockout filter list with many select lists

Tags: knockout.js, filtered-index

I am trying to accomplish the following when filtering a collection in knockout.

1. Render dropdownlists based off the collection of data (I did this)
2. Use multiple dropdownlists to filter the collection (currently I can only use one, ugh)
3. When the collection is filtered with whatever select list, all other select lists will update with the options available for the new filtered collection

   [image: table example]

Index view model:

```
var bindingsComplete = false
    , vm = new vm()
    , urlparts = document.location.pathname.split(/\/|\?|&|=|\./g)
    , query = urlparts[3]
    , count = urlparts[4]
    , page = urlparts[5]
    , filterProperty = function (value, name) {
        var _this = this;
        _this.optionsVal = value;
        _this.optionsTxt = name;
    };

function vehicle(asvId, vName, vPrice, vClass) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.AllStockVehiclesId = ko.observable(asvId);
    _this.VehicleMakeName = ko.observable(vName);
    _this.VehicleRetailPrice = ko.observable(vPrice);
    _this.VehicleClass = ko.observable(vClass);
}

function createSelectList(data, propertyArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i++) {
        var property = propertyArray[i];
        var optionsArray = new Array();
        for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length - 1; ii++) {
            var option = data[ii][property];
            if (optionsArray.indexOf(option) == -1) {
                optionsArray.push(option);
                vm.selectList[property].options.push(new filterProperty(option, option));
            }
        }
    }
}

function vm() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.vehicles = ko.observableArray([]);
    _this.filter = ko.observable();
    _this.selectList = {
        VehicleMakeName: {
            options: ko.observableArray([])
            , selectValue: ko.observable()
        },
        VehicleClass: {
            options: ko.observableArray([])
            , selectValue: ko.observable()
        }
        , changedState: ko.observable()
    }
    selectListChanged = function(event) {
        console.log('change')
    }
    //_this.filterVehicles = _this.vehicles.filterByProperty('VehicleClass', 'C');
    _this.filterVehicles = ko.computed(function ()
    {
        if (_this.selectList.VehicleMakeName.selectValue() == undefined) {
            return _this.vehicles();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(_this.vehicles(), function (vehicle) {
                return vehicle.VehicleMakeName() == _this.selectList.VehicleMakeName.selectValue();
            });
        }
    });

    _this.rvClass = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(_this.selectList.VehicleClass.options(), function (item) {
            for (var i = 0; i < _this.filterVehicles().length; i++) {
                if (item.optionsVal === _this.filterVehicles()[i].VehicleClass()) {
                    //console.log(item.optionsVal);
                    //vm.selectList.VehicleClass.options.push(new filterProperty(item.optionsTxt, item.optionsVal))
                }
            }
        });
    })
/*
    _this.selectList.selectValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        _this.filterVehicles = _this.vehicles.filterByProperty('VehicleClass', newValue);
    })*/

    /*test = _this.filterVehicles;
    _this.selectList.VehicleClass.selectValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        _this.filterVehicles = _this.vehicles.filterByProperty('VehicleClass', newValue);
    })*/
}

ld.ajax.browse.Vehicles(query, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        vm.vehicles.push(new vehicle(
            data[i].AllStockVehiclesId
            , data[i].VehicleMakeName
            , data[i].VehicleRetailPrice
            , data[i].VehicleClass
        ));
    }
    var propertyArray = ['VehicleMakeName', 'VehicleClass'];
    createSelectList(data, propertyArray);
})

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

View:

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Stock #
            </td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: selectList.VehicleMakeName.options
                                    , optionsText: 'optionsTxt'
                                    , optionsValue: 'optionsVal'
                                    , value: selectList.VehicleMakeName.selectValue
                                    , optionsCaption: 'VehicleMakeName', event: { change: selectListChanged }"></select>
            </td>
            <td>Price
            </td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: selectList.VehicleClass.options
                                    , optionsText: 'optionsTxt'
                                    , optionsValue: 'optionsVal'
                                    , value: selectList.VehicleClass.selectValue
                                    , optionsCaption: 'Class', event: { change: selectListChanged }"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: filterVehicles">
        <tr class="vehicle">
            <!--img data-bind="attr: { src: AllStockVehiclesId, title: '' }" /-->
            <td data-bind="text: AllStockVehiclesId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: VehicleMakeName"></td>
            <td data-bind="money: VehicleRetailPrice"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: VehicleClass"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I created [a plunker which filters like you described above](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntrhz0vmHDNB4JQnOvky?p=preview). Perhaps you can use that as a help to get further on your way?

Comment: @robert.westerlund - Only thing that is giving me trouble is when I try to substitute your for loop at the top with an ajax call it messes up because it executes the ajax after it calls the viewmodel. So in the debugger if I set my break point on line 2 and line 22 with your code it executes 2 first so it renders properly. With mine when I replace the code block starting in line with AJAX and rerun it it goes to the viewmodel code in line 22 first and thus messes it all up.

Comment: I have updated the plunker to load the vehicle list asynchronously using a very ugly fake promise. Press the added button to "execute the AJAX call" to retrieve data.

Comment: @robert.westerlund - Thanks! Is there a way to load it up on page load, without a button?

Comment: Yes, just execute the function immediately when the viewmodel is created instead of having a button bind the click event to it.